# "resource" property is ignored in my keycloak.json

Tags: security, configuration, resources, war, keycloak

I have secured a WAR which contains my web services.
I've added the following keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "myRealm",
  "auth-server-url": "*****************",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "WS",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "enable-cors": true,
  "principal-attribute" : "preferred_username"
}
```

And I've added on keycloak the "WS" client with bearer-only true and an other client to generate my token.

Everything work fine, the war is secured.
BUT I don't think the name given in my "resource" property changes anything.
If I write "resource": "anything" or "resource": "onetwothree" ... It will still work..

I don't understand why, I thought I will receive an error like the resource "onetwothree" doesn't exist or else but it still work and I think there is something wrong...
Do you have an idea what it could be ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from Sebastien Blanc that I share with you, perhaps it may help one of you..

*It's because of the "bearer-only" nature of your client. Only the token is verified.  In some cases it could use the 'resource' property if for instance "use-resource-role-mappings" is used (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java#L99-L103)*

So that is a normal behavior, I can set any value to the "resource" attribute because I don't set the "use-resource-role-mappings" to true and the value is false by default.